# Error checking in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, syntax

I can't get this working for some reason =/
Been googling all day and no luck

I created a function called cFunc to do my error checking and i call it every time after the user input to let them know the information they added is not valid. But for some reason this is not working. Any help would be great!

```
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int loanAmount; //amount of the loan
double loanInterest; // the loan interest rate
int loanYears; //years of the loan
int loanTerm = loanYears; //loan term in months
double loanPay; //variable for outputting the payment

int main()
{
cout<<"Enter Loan Amount";
cin>>loanAmount;
cFunc();
cout<<"Enter Loan Interest";
cin>>loanInterest;
cFunc();
cout<<"Enter Loan Years";
cin>>loanYears;
cFunc();


loanPay = (loanAmount * loanInterest) / (1 - pow(1+loanInterest,-loanYears)); //Formula to figure mortgage payment amount

cout<< "Your Monthly Payment Amount is: $"<< loanPay; //prints out monthly payment amount
return 0;
}

void cFunc(){
    int main(){
    cout << "Enter an int: ";
    int x = 0;
    while(!(cin >> x)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "You enterd: " << x << endl;           
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: You must declare your function before the main! (declare, not define, just a `void cFunc();` before the main definition is enough) [Edit: Wait, why is there another main function defined in the body of `cFunc`? What is it supposed to be?] [Edit2: and why are you returning `x` in a function returning `void`? are you sure you spent a day looking for the reasons behind these errors?]

Comment: "Not working" means "Fails to compile, with a specific error"?  Or something else?  *What* is not working, to your satisfaction?

Comment: Sorry, some changes were made and this is what i am at now

http://pastebin.com/VJtpZ36f

at the bottom i did load instead of loan if you see that

Comment: @Caninonos Why? Cargo cult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i see:
In the function you have declared a main.
Second:
I included the prototype of the function
Third:
The funcion has been declared void, and, return an int, why?

This is the code working. At least, logically.
good luck, and if you need something, let me know

```
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int loanAmount; //amount of the loan
double loanInterest; // the loan interest rate
int loanYears; //years of the loan
int loanTerm = loanYears; //loan term in months
double loanPay; //variable for outputting the payment

void cFunc();

int main()
{
cout<<"Enter Loan Amount";
cin>>loanAmount;
cFunc();
cout<<"Enter Loan Interest";
cin>>loanInterest;
cFunc();
cout<<"Enter Loan Years";
cin>>loanYears;
cFunc();


loanPay = (loanAmount * loanInterest) / (1 - pow(1+loanInterest,-loanYears)); //Formula to figure mortgage payment amount

cout<< "Your Monthly Payment Amount is: $"<< loanPay; //prints out monthly payment amount
return 0;
}

void cFunc(){
    cout << "Enter an int: ";
    int x = 0;
    while(!(cin >> x)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "You enterd: " << x << endl;
    // Why have a return int a function declared void?
    // return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you did. Is there any way to make it check over all instead of each time so it doesnt repeat enter an int? I am still relatively new to c++ so all this information i am reading on here is great.


I declared a main to house the code? I don't really understand what you are asking here. As to the void i am still learning but i thought i could create a function to house the code i can run instead of copy pasting a bunch of stuff after each user input

Comment: Well, you can charge all the values into the vars, and passing to the function, returning an int, for each value has an error.
Some pseudocode here

cin >> var1;
cin >> var2;
 if (Check_Values(Var1, Var2) == 1)
{
     Var1 = error;
} else if ( Check_Values(Var1,Var2) == 2)
{
   Var2 = error;
}

Comment: You have you got in mind that the compiler, doesnt know all the code you have write. 
only know the first lines , before last , so if you put your function at the end when you make the call to that function , if there is no prototype or the function itself , before that call, it will not recognize the command , so it will give a compile error .
there are two ways to solve . The good , is to add a .h file, which has the functions , and the not so good , in your main.cpp , put all function prototypes .
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help everyone? I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From the code on pastebin

```
void _loanAmount(int x) {
    cout<<"Enter Loan Amount";
    cin>>loanAmount;

    while (!(cin >> x)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "Please enter a numerical value" << endl;
    }
}
```

should be

```
void _loanAmount() {
    cout<<"Enter Loan Amount";
    while (!(cin >> loanAmount)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "Please enter a numerical value" << endl;
    }
}
```

You're likely adapting code you've seen elsewhere without sufficient understanding what you are doing. As one of the comments said earlier this is cargo cult programming. Stop googling and read a book would be my advice.

Comment: I was looking for an error check code and i thought i understood it but it turns out i was wrong. I appreciate the info